Create dataframe from series containing lists of dictionaries
I have a dataframe containing a column where each row is a list of dictionaries.
 | Column A | 
1| [{'A':1, 'B':2}] | 
2| [{'A':3, 'B':4}, {'A':5, 'B':6}] | 
...

How can a create another dataframe from this series?
  | A | B |
  | - | - |
1 | 1 | 2 |
2 | 3 | 4 |
  | 5 | 6 |
... 

I've tried pd.DataFrame but it only seems to work with a single list of dictionaries.

If you have an unusual series like dictionaries in the cells, please provide your sample input as code.

Example Code
I'll provide a sample code similar to your example
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': [{'A':1, 'B':2}, [{'A':3, 'B':4}, {'A':5, 'B':6}]]})

df
    colA
0   {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
1   [{'A': 3, 'B': 4}, {'A': 5, 'B': 6}]


Code
Let's isolate and explode only the rows with cells where the list exists, then concatenate them again and use json_normalize
cond1 = df['colA'].map(type).eq(list)
out = (pd.concat([df[cond1].explode('colA'), df[~cond1]])
         .sort_index()
         .reset_index()
         .pipe(lambda x: x[['index']].join(pd.json_normalize(x['colA'])))
)

out
    index   A   B
0   0       1   2
1   1       3   4
2   1       5   6

If you don't need the index column, delete it
